# How to paste multiple cells with the same date from one worksheet to another?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to copy data with the same date from one worksheet to another using VBA.
I want to apply a loop so that this happens automatically every day.

```vb
Sub CopyOverDeviceRecords() 

Dim DateCol As Range 
Dim Today As Range 
Dim PasteCell As Range 

Set DateCol = Tracker.Range("B") 

For Each Today In DateCol 

    If Communications.Range("E13") = "" Then 
        Set PasteCell = Communications.Range("E13") Else 
        Set PasteCell = Communications.Range("E12").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) 
    End If 

    If Today = Date Then 
        Today.Offset(0, -4).Resize(1, 5).Copy PasteCell

Next Today 

End Sub
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [reprex] and take the [tour].

Comment: Please provide data, desired result and what you've tried.

Comment: I want to paste data in **Column C** from the **Tracker sheet** to **Communications sheet** based on **today's date in Column B**, I want the data to be pasted in E13 and below cells. How should I modify this code to get the desired output?

Comment: @user16189940 don't drop the code into the comments, and instead update your question with it and be more specific. Saying this cell and that cell doesn't explain too much about how the sheet works and your objectives for those of us who haven't seen it. You mention cell E13 and below: all cells, only cells where the cell adjacent has the same date, etc. Try to explain it in a way that we have a clear idea of what's expected and how your sheet is structured.

Comment: So do you accept / have read the proposal submitted below (or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack**overflow**!

### 0] Approach in a nutshell

Three key parts to this proposed solution/approach:

1. VB code
2. Macro Security Settings
3. Task Scheduler

Briefly, will write code that updates the table (copies across all rows that correspond to 'today's date', every time the workbook is opened (assuming another day has gone passed, otherwise opening/closing won't do anything).  Will then utilise Task-Scheduler to 'mimic' what you intended when you described 'loop to repeat exercise every day' (having a loop constantly running with Excel open the entire time hardly feels optimal/efficient - it may even jam-up operation as VB spins in a constant loop routine...).  You could consider some kind of 'call back' or event-triggered activity, but the former is beyond the scope for a beginner VB candidate (and myself for that matter, have only used this feature in Python etc.) and the latter is likely to lead to inconsistent behaviour - which may or may not update the date depending upon whether there was interaction with the spreadsheet, etc.).

### 1] Screenshot

[image: Excel screenshot & assoc. VB - Workbook_Open()]

Excel template (w/ code) [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wOmT4zyqSi2qdjpjKS8lYcZlclNTiMn236h9bYnmkww/edit?usp=sharing).

### 2] Macro steps

1. Open VB (alt + F11) - windows CPU
2. Find the sheet in question in project explorer menu, and double click to open the window pane for writing VB code
3. At the top of this pane there'll be 2 drop downs - select "Worksheet" from the left menu dropdown, and "Open" from the right (a Private Sub_Open() followed by 'End Sub' will appear.
4. Modify this to look like above.

### 3] VB code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Sheets("67925939").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Call copy
    'Sheets.Calculate
End Sub



Sub copy()
    Today = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Today_old = Format(Range("o3").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    If Today > Today_old Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Days = Format(Today, "d") - Format(Today_old, "d")
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Range("o3").Formula = "=today()"
        Range("o3").Value = Range("o3").Value


        For i = 1 To Days
            d = Format(Today, "dd")
            M = Format(Today, "mm")
            Y = Format(Today, "yyyy")
            Range("H1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Formula2R1C1 = "=FILTER(R5C2:R500C6,R5C2:R500C2=date(" & Y & "," & M & "," & d - i & "))"
            'optional: hardcopy results
            If Range("o4").Value = "Yes" Then
                Range("h1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Select
                Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
                Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
                Selection.copy
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
         Next
        Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        'ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

End Sub
```

**Notes:**
To repeat each day, we're going to use Task Scheduler (Windows) - this will open the workbook at a specified time each day.  The workbook VB code (above), upon opening, will check whether the last saved date (cell o3, screenshot above) is < today's date (it will run the macro for each day difference).

### 4] Macro Settings

Pre-requisites to running macro automatically upon opening the workbook:

1. Digitally signed macro (self signing certificate)
2. From within Excel, go: Tools, Options, Trust Centre, Trust Centre Settings
3. Configure (at your own risk) Macro Settings per screenshots below

Note: the first time you open this workbook, you'll be presented with a popup / message: select 'always run/trust from this publisher'.  This should be one-off (won't appear again).

[image: Macro Settings - Trust Centre]

[image: Disable all except Digitally Signed]

Read [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01) to create self-signing certificate.

### 5] Task scheduler

To setup a daily task scheduler that will open the workbook at a specified time each day, go ahead and:

1. Open Notepad, paste the full location and file name (with extension, e.g. "C:\Users\YourName\Project\MyWorkbork.xlsm".  Save under a relevant name, and then change extension from .txt to '.bat' and accept warning message re potential file corruption when making changes to extension directly. You can also elect to save more directly - e.g. 'save as type', 'all files',  include '.bat' at the end of relevant bat file name.
2. Hit Win + X
3. Select 'Computer Management'
4. Right click on Task Scheduler Library (left hand pane) and add a new folder, enter some relevant folder name (here, 'StackOverflow' - first screenshot below)
5. Right click in the middle-top pane (blank, per below) and select from the context menu 'create new task'
6. Proceed to configure per ensuing screenshots...
7. Test scheduler by setting start time (Trigger menu/dialogue) to commence in 1-2 mins time.

[image: Task Scheduler Library]

**Configuration guide**

*Enter relevant task name*
[image: Enter relevant name for this daily task (here: 'Test')]

*Triggers - create new, select daily at desired time of day*

[image: Triggers - daily]

*Actions - Start Program/Script - browse for your excel file*

[image]

*Fancy a slightly different approach to achieve same effect? See [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/how-to-automatically-run-excel-vba-macros-daily).*

### 6] Functional / customizing

**Prerequisites**

- Requires Office 365
- Requires macro-enabled workbook (.xlsm, .xlsb, etc.), preferably with a digitally signed or self-signing certificate (to offer some protection, otherwise [not recommended] - enable all Macros in the security settings (Excel: tools/options/trust centre etc.) - again NOT ADVISED

**Customize VB code to cater for different source/destination locations in Excel**

- Revise 'Range(H1).end().end()..' to Range(desired destination cell) to overwrite instead of append - beware of overlap if previous results had more rows though(!)
- Take note of VB's 'R1C1' referencing when customising code to suit your setup (i.e. location of today's date, o3, or destination table etc.)

**Other notes**

- Select 'Yes' or 'No' to hardcopy values in destination range (applies to entire table)